# Show that group $\Sigma_3$ can be write as $\mathbb{Z}/ 3\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

Definition.
Given a group $K$ with subgroups $G$ and $H$ satisfying
(i) $K = GH$, i.e., every element $k \in K$ can be written $k = gh$ where $g \in G$ and $h\in H$
(ii) $G K$
(iii) $G\vartriangleleft H = {1}$
we then say that $K$ is the semidirect product $G \rtimes H$.

Definition.
$\Sigma_l$ acts on $\mathbb{E} = \mathbb{R}^l = \{(X_l,..., X_l)\}$ by
permuting coordinates. We thereby obtain a subgroup $\Sigma_l \subset  O(\mathbb{E})$. $O(\mathbb{E}) = \{f: \mathbb{E} \to \mathbb{E} linear and  (f(x),f(y))= (x,y) for all x,y \in \mathbb{E} \}$
be the orthogonal group of lEThis subgroup
is a reflection group.

I found that $\mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by the involution $(1,2)$. But I don't understand why it is involution? And how I can write this formula? Also I found that  $\mathbb{Z}/ 3\mathbb{Z} $ is generated by the cycle $(1,2,3)$. But why we have $\Sigma_3 =\mathbb{Z}/ 3\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z}$?

Cycle $(1,2,3)$ means that $1 \to 2$, $2\to 3$ and $3 \to 1$.

Comment: What is $\Sigma_3$ and what is the definition of the fancy multiplying operator you wrote?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @BenjaminWang $\rtimes$ means semidirect product

Comment: @DavidLui There is some merit to having the poster themselves answering that question. I am sure Benjamin Wang actually knew what the symbol is commonly used for. And even if he didn't, I would still wait to see if Mathewg would reply.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying set of a semidirect product is the direct product of the underlying sets, so $\mathbb{Z}/ 3\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z}$ has order 6.

By definition of multiplication in a semidirect product, $(a, b) * (a' , b') = (a \phi(b)(a') , b b')$, where $\phi : \mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{Z}/ 3\mathbb{Z})$ send $0$ to the identity and $1$ to negation.

We have $(1, 1) * (2, 1) =(1 +\phi(1)(2), 0)  = (1-2, 0) = (2, 0)$

while $(2, 1)*(1, 1) = (2 + \phi(1)(1), 0) = (2-1, 0) = (1, 0)$

Therefore the group is not abelian. The only non-abelian group of order 6 is $S_3$.